# Is it possible to play GH:On tour without the guitar pick?

Tags: guitar-hero-on-tour

I'm willing to buy the game to play on my DS lite but I think it is very uncomfortable to play using the guitar pick (i'm used to play Guitar Hero on ps2 using the dualshock,not the guitar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a ***very*** long time since I played this, but, while it is possible to use your finger (or more accurately, your finger**nail**) to strum, it is much less reliable. Similarly, you can use a stylus. The guitar pick is more for stylistic purposes.

However, if you're asking if it's possible to play without using the touch screen, it is not.

Comment: I was wondering if I could use a stylus,you 'nailed' it,thank you!